# Why did i failed calling JPanel from another JPanel on the same JFrame?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

i'm new to Java and JFrame. on my project, i'm learning to make multiple panels on the same JFrame using JPanel. but when i code a function of the button on my 1st JPanel (i want it to go show another JPanel) it gives me an error, here is my full code :

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */
package Main;

import GUI.Menu;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 *
 * @author rizkiaswangga
 */
public class Start extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Start
     */
    public Start() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        windowPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jLayeredPane1 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
        Menu = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        Browse = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Library = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextPane1.setEditable(false);
        jTextPane1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jTextPane1.setText("Game Store");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout windowPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(windowPanel);
        windowPanel.setLayout(windowPanelLayout);
        windowPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            windowPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(windowPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(404, 404, 404)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        windowPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            windowPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(windowPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jLayeredPane1.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

        Browse.setText("Browse");
        Browse.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BrowseActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout MenuLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Menu);
        Menu.setLayout(MenuLayout);
        MenuLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            MenuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, MenuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(813, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(Browse)
                .addGap(146, 146, 146))
        );
        MenuLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            MenuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, MenuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(231, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(Browse)
                .addGap(187, 187, 187))
        );

        jLayeredPane1.add(Menu, "card2");

        jLabel1.setText("test");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout LibraryLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Library);
        Library.setLayout(LibraryLayout);
        LibraryLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            LibraryLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(LibraryLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(188, 188, 188)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(790, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        LibraryLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            LibraryLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(LibraryLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(124, 124, 124)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(268, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jLayeredPane1.add(Library, "card3");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(windowPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jLayeredPane1))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(windowPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLayeredPane1))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void BrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) getContentPane().getLayout();
    cardLayout.show(getContentPane(), "Library");
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Start().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void switchPanels(Menu panel){
        
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Browse;
    private javax.swing.JPanel Library;
    private javax.swing.JPanel Menu;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel windowPanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

most of the code is generated automatically by Netbeans' JFrame Form Design tab. the only part that i modify is :

```
    private void BrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) getContentPane().getLayout();
    cardLayout.show(getContentPane(), "Library");
    }
```

i watched online tutorials on how to show JPanel from another JPanel, but on my cased it failed by giving me a message on the output whenever i click the button :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be cast to class java.awt.CardLayout (javax.swing.GroupLayout and java.awt.CardLayout are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')
    at Main.Start.BrowseActionPerformed(Start.java:139)
    at Main.Start$1.actionPerformed(Start.java:70)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

below is the screenshot of the Navigator tab of my components (at that part is showing the "Menu"  panel which has the button that i would want to show the "Library" panel when clicked :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgXoa.png)

i'm sure something is wrong on my code :(...any help would be appreciated

I tried asking the code from ChatGPT and watching online tutorials

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong -- your JPanel that your getting the layout from is using GroupLayout, not Cardlayout. The solution is to use CardLayout and not GroupLayout. I suggest that you avoid NetBeans code generation until you understand how Swing and especially how the layout managers work.

Comment: In fact, where do you call `setLayout(new CardLayout())` on any container? CardLayout won't magically appear, you have to add it to the GUI to the container that uses it.

Comment: Please check out the [CardLayout Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). It will show you how to use this layout and is a much better resource for this problem then ChatGPT.